# Minus and plus value for Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, amcharts

I have some date each has plus or minus value (for example assets or 
liabilities)

So at first I integrated [nested piechart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/nested-donut-chart/) by amchart

However it has some weak points, you can't get the defference of assets and liabilities at a glance

So next idea is to use like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qfZT.png),discussed [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89598/how-to-show-negative-values-in-a-pie-chart)

However I cant find the good sample for amchart4.

Is there any good sample or close sample???

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this with d3pie chart(see attached image). This is the site: http://d3pie.org/website/examples/donut.html
Just set the stroke to 1 and the `fill` to `white` for example. The rest of the stuff I guess is some Math, and you should manipulate the `DOM` to change those.

[image: k]

Comment: Thank you for nice suggestion. However I would like to use amchart. Since I already used this for other graphs

Answer (score 0):

The pie chart you want to do, beside looking cool, doesn't apply to this scenario/calculation, especially the percentages are misleading (total being the sum of absolute values of all numbers).

Pie chart is suitable for visualization of all items from the same category. For example, your spending for the month:

[image]

which includes Utilities, Transportation, Groceries, etc.

Would a `ColumnSeries` make more sense in this case?

[image]

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/tna84zer/

Comment: At first I have debated between Column and Pie. However  I want to know the Ratio of each data at a glance. Column is not good for this purpose. So far, my current solution is making two pie for plus value and minus value. It can show the each detailed ratio of minus and plus, but it doesn't show the ratio of between minus and plus....

Comment: @whitebear: "know the Ratio of each data" - counting the absolute value of the negative value as part of the total doesn't make sense in term of percentage. Yes by doing that you get the percentage but what does that mean? In my example of income and spending, I treated everything as positive values, then you can get a Pie chart out of it with meaning. If you have to go for Pie Chart, I would suggest you treat minus value as positive, and maybe have another field in your data to display as negative? In that way, this would be just a simple Pie Chart with "minus" values having a dash border?

Comment: To add to David's suggestion, having another field in the data would also allow you to adjust things like the `tooltipText` and what not as well (whether manually or via an `adapter`).